# Cannot convert PDF to image using PHP and ImageMagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

```
CentOS 6.7 x64
PHP 5.5.28
GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)
ImageMagick 6.9.1-6 Q16 x86_64 2015-06-25
```

I need to convert a PDF to an image as follows:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/convert -density 300 /path/to/file.pdf -resize 25% -compress lossless -quality 0 /path/to/file.jpg');
?>
```

However the output from this command is:

```
Unknown device: pamcmyk32
Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice Operand stack:
    defaultdevice
```

If I execute the exact same command via SSH, it works! But why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by downgrading to ImageMagick 6.9.1-4.